# Execute a program and bind it to the network

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to write a program that works like ssh, I found ssh can "bring" the remote machine's cmd.exe (or /bin/sh) locally. I don't find any subprocess or os function can do that.

I tried subprocess.run, subprocess.Popen to execute remote command (I need the client to ask me for input) but when I input commands like "more", "cmd.exe" it will freeze the client program. And that works differently from ssh, I need it to bring the remote machine's shell locally, not execute commands that are input-ed by asking me what command to execute.

Comment: If you want to give the user a temporary ssh shell, then for gosh sakes just run `ssh`.  Note that ssh does exactly what you say in the last sentence.  There's a server on the other end that's submitting the commands and returning the output to the local ssh instance.  It's not "bringing the shell locally".

Comment: yeah, but ssh give me the similar experience of working with shells locally. I can't find how to implement it in python.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you want to present a remote shell to your app's user, then use `subprocess.run` to run `ssh`.  Why reinvent the wheel?  What value would you be adding?  There is a module called `paramiko` that lets you access the `ssh` protocol, but then you would have to do the terminal handling and pass the commands and results back and forth.